# Files lost during upgrade from VPS3 to VPS4 in GoDaddy: Unable to locate files on VPS4 server

Tags: ssh, vps, web-hosting, putty, godaddy

I recently experienced an automatic upgrade from VPS3 to VPS4 on GoDaddy after the expiration of my VPS3 server. However, I am facing difficulties in locating my website files on the new VPS4 server. I have also purchased a new VPS4 plan, but I cannot find the files that were previously hosted on VPS3.

To access the VPS4 server, I have been using PuTTY through SSH. When I navigate to the directory where the files should be located and execute the command "ls -l," it returns "total 0," indicating that there are no files present in the directory.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or assistance in retrieving my lost files. How can I locate the files that were stored on the VPS3 server or determine if they were properly transferred to the VPS4 server during the upgrade process?